# How to put an image from s3 bucket to Python list

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How can I put images from s3 bucket to Python list?

I am trying to convert an image from s3 bucket to img array like

```
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Conv2DTranspose, UpSampling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dense, Dropout, Flatten, InputLayer
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.models import model_from_json
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img
from skimage.color import rgb2lab, lab2rgb, rgb2gray
from skimage.io import imsave
import numpy as np
import os
import random
import tensorflow as tf

# Get images
import boto.s3.connection
conn = boto.s3.connect_to_region('us-east-2',
       aws_access_key_id='mykey',
       aws_secret_access_key='mysecretkey',
       calling_format = boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat(),
       )
bucket = conn.get_bucket('datasettrainimage123')

X = []
for filename in bucket.list():
    X.append(img_to_array(load_img(filename.key.split('/')[-1])))
X = np.array(X, dtype = float)
```

I end up getting this error

```
No such file or directory: '02_0004.jpg'
```

Comment: This depends on what are `load_img` and `img_to_array` none of which is shown in your question.

Comment: sorry, its keras.preprocessing.image methods

Comment: Did you check if `load_img` works with S3? Seems it does not.

Comment: I think in my case i am getting just the name of the image, how can i get the image object? If this is not the case, then how can I get the object from 3 bucket?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `boto` its better to use [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html) as it is current. In boto3 there is [download_file](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.download_file) which will allow you download an image from s3 into your local storage. Once yo do this, you can read it in using `load_img`.

Comment: But I am using AWS SageMaker (namely Notebook instances) to build and train the keras model on cloud GPU and CPU. How do I access local files in this case?